Routing WAN IP to Local Network
My ISP has change my IP address to a new subnet.  Their setup now makes it impossible for me to connect to my own WAN IP from that IP.  What I mean is if my ISP assigned IP address is 1.2.3.4 and I tried to connect to 1.2.3.4 from my local network, I cannot.  If I try to connect to 1.2.3.4 from some other address, like 4.3.2.1, it works fine.  I've seen this happen before and understand it is something in my ISP's routing rules.  It is almost guaranteed they are not going to understand what I'm talking about, yet alone attempt to fix the issue.
I run a DD-WRT router, and I think I should be able to create a router rule.  Unfortunately, this is an area I know almost nothing about.  I'm not even sure the search terms I should use to find a solution.  I am comfortable in Linux, have used iptables before, and don't mind reading if I know where to start.

this sounds like a lack of NAT hairpinning.

Sounds like Browser caching to me.  You can try CtrlF5 on Windows.  But you probably need to Reset your Browser's cache.

No, it is most definitely not browser caching.  I cannot SSH, telnet, curl or wget to my public IP address from that address.
